# What are "Multi Return" functions?

Tags: c++, function, methods, return

An example is this:

```
void DLL_EXPORT MyDLLFunction();
```

What is the secondary returnish like thing (in this case "DLL_EXPORT")?

Comment: have you tried Google it first? https://www.google.com/search?q=DLL_EXPORT&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

That is not a return value. It says to compiler, that function will be used within DLL library and so steps during compilation are made.

Answer (score 1):

A "multi return" function is simply a function which has more that one point at which it may return to the caller.  For example:

```
bool IsOdd(uint32_t n)
{
  if (n%2)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```

However, the body of your question is completely orthogonal to this.  `DLL_EXPORT` is not a return type here, but a compiler directive describing how the function should be named (see [Name Mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)) and what sort of [calling conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are to be used.